# How to create groups and grant different permissions in AWS Cognito in Serverless

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, serverless-framework

I am creating an app using serverless framework in AWS. I am using NodeJS to write Lambda. In the application I want create two different roles

1. Admin
2. Users

In my `serverless.yaml` file I have created two different Cognito User pool groups for these user types

```
AdminUserPoolGroup:
      Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPoolGroup
      Properties:
        GroupName: "admins"
        Precedence: 0
        UserPoolId: 
          Ref: CognitoUserPool

NormalUserPoolGroup:
      Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPoolGroup
      Properties: 
        GroupName: users
        Precedence: 1
        UserPoolId:
          Ref: CognitoUserPool
```

I want to grant different access levels to these two groups for an example admins can create posts, users can only view them. After doing some research I found that this can be done by attaching policies to groups. But I could not find a way to do that by using serverless framework.

Answer (score 6):

You need to specify the [`RoleArn`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cognito-userpoolgroup.html#cfn-cognito-userpoolgroup-rolearn) property of the [`AWS::Cognito::UserPoolGroup`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cognito-userpoolgroup.html) resource:

```yaml
AdminUserPoolGroup:
  Type: 'AWS::Cognito::UserPoolGroup'
  Properties:
    GroupName: "admins"
    Precedence: 0
    UserPoolId: !Ref CognitoUserPool
    RoleArn: !GetAtt AdminRole.Arn # Get the ARN of the role defined below

AdminRole: # The IAM role for admins
  Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
  Properties:
    ...role properties...
```

See [`AWS::IAM::Role`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-role.html) on how to define a role (you will have to declare [`AWS::IAM::Policy`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-policy.html) resources and reference them in your role).

Comment: What does AdminRole's AssumeRolePolicyDocument look like?

Comment: @Corey see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/role-trust-and-permissions.html for an example